# Can't seed torrents with WebTorrent in Chrome extension service worker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, webtorrent

I'm having some trouble using WebTorrent in a Chrome extension. I can download torrents with a service worker, but I can't seed them.

When I load the extension below, it prints a magnet link, as expected. However, when I try to download the file it's seeding with the webpage below, it doesn't work. The download never starts. Other WebTorrent clients like [instant.io](https://instant.io) also don't work.

If I create a second webpage and copy the extension's code there, it works perfectly.

I am aware that service workers "go to sleep" after 30 seconds, or 5 minutes if there's an open port. I've checked, and the service worker is running.

**Chrome Extension**

`background.js`

```js
importScripts('webtorrent.min.js');

var client = new WebTorrent();
client.seed(new File(['Testing testing'], 'test.txt'), function(torrent) {
    console.log(torrent.magnetURI);
});
```

`manifest.json`

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Testing",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    }
}
```

**Webpage**

`main.js`

```js
var client = new WebTorrent();
client.add('magnet:?xt=urn:btih:5825068c75bede26bb19f53...', function(torrent) {
    torrent.files[0].appendTo('body');
});
```

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="webtorrent.min.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

I'm using the latest versions of the Brave browser and WebTorrent. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use devtools to debug the code of your background script. [How to see background.js console?](/a/10258029) If there are no errors, it's possible that webtorrent simply doesn't work in a service worker and you should open a new tab instead.

Comment: That's where it printed the magnet link. There are no errors. I guess I'll have to do it a different way.